# MySQL вложенные запросы одинаковые значения

Tags: mysql, select

Добрый день!

есть запрос

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(`week`.`id`) AS `cell1`,
  COUNT(`months`.`id`) AS `cell2`
FROM
  (SELECT 
     *
   FROM
     `contract`
   WHERE
     `contract`.date_create BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2017-10-01  00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE('2017-10-30 23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
        AND `contract`.`vidan_flag` = '1'
        AND `contract`.`filial_id` = 4) as months,
  (SELECT 
     *
  FROM
     `contract`
  WHERE
     `contract`.date_create BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2017-10-23  00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE('2017-10-30 23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
        AND `contract`.`vidan_flag` = '1'
        AND `contract`.`filial_id` = 4) as week
LIMIT 1;
```

И вот вопрос запрос выдает одинаковые значения в обе ячейки, а если убрать все что связано с одной из колонок значение коректно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логично. Вы же тупо перемножаете все строки. Если хочется странного, то пишите уже так

```
SELECT 
  `week`.`cnt` AS `cell1`,
  `months`.`cnt` AS `cell2`
FROM
  (SELECT 
     COUNT(`id`) AS `cnt`
   FROM
     `contract`
   WHERE
     `contract`.date_create BETWEEN '2017-10-01  00:00:00' AND '2017-10-30 23:59:59'
     AND `contract`.`vidan_flag` = '1'
     AND `contract`.`filial_id` = 4) as months,
  (SELECT 
     *
  FROM
     `contract`
  WHERE
     `contract`.date_create BETWEEN '2017-10-23  00:00:00' AND '2017-10-30 23:59:59'
     AND `contract`.`vidan_flag` = '1'
     AND `contract`.`filial_id` = 4) as week
```

Но, учитывая, что Вам нужны одни и те же данные, я бы сам делал так

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(`ctr`.`id`) AS `cnt_month`
  SUM(IF(
    ctr.date_create BETWEEN '2017-10-23  00:00:00' AND '2017-10-30 23:59:59',
    1,
    0
  )) AS `cnt_week`
FROM
  `contract` ctr
WHERE
  ctr.date_create BETWEEN '2017-10-01  00:00:00' AND '2017-10-30 23:59:59'
  AND ctr.`vidan_flag` = '1'
  AND ctr.`filial_id` = 4
```

P.S. Смысла использования `STR_TO_DATE` я не понял

Comment: руководствовался http://tigor.com.ua/blog/2008/08/23/date_comparison_by_between_operator_of_mysql/

Comment: А как без странного

Comment: @АнтонКартушин Без странного написал

Comment: Увидел спасибо, сейчас буду разбирать

Answer (score 1):

count() считает строки в выборке где значение указанного поля не NULL. ID всегда не NULL значит оба count() считают просто кол-во строк в выборке и поэтому значения совпадают. При этом вы пишите две выборки через запятую и не указываете условий объединения, следовательно в выборку попадает каждая строка из первого запроса с каждой строкой из второго и в итоге кол-во записей в первой и второй перемножается.

Я бы переписал ваш запрос в таком виде:

```
   SELECT count(*) as month,
          sum(case when date_create >= '2017-10-23'
                    and date_create < '2017-10-30'+interval 1 day
              then 1 else 0) as week
     FROM `contract`
    WHERE date_create >= '2017-10-01' AND date_create < '2017-10-30'+interval 1 day
      AND `contract`.`vidan_flag` = '1'
      AND `contract`.`filial_id` = 4
```

Интервалы дат в принципе можете оставить как у вас были, я решил сделать более короткий вариант для чего between включающий обе граничные даты заменил на два условия, одно из которых на строгое "меньше" следующего дня.

Количества считаются одним запросом, `count(*)` дает общее кол-во строк попавших под условие в where, `sum(...)` суммирует единицы по заданному внутри условию. В случае если неделя не лежит строго в месяце, а выходит за его пределы, условие в where должно включать весь диапазон, что бы захватить и неделю и месяц и при этом первый `count()` надо заменить на такой же `sum()` как для недели, только с другим интервалом дат.